# Custom Content on WordPress Dashboard

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out the best way about going and adding custom content to my wordpress dashboard that will be defined in my admin panel.

So essentially I'll have my admin account be able to set certain settings, and the other users (subscribers, editors, etc...) will see the custom dashboard when they login (the admin will see it as well).

So far I've cleared the entire dashboard, and know how to add a widget to it but I'm trying to add custom html instead (without the widget box).

Any suggestions/ideas? I'd love some help with this one, thanks!

Comment: Would something like this work or are you more interested in learning to customize the dashboard with the PHP API? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/

Comment: I used several ideas for my plugin from adminimize, it's a great start. But I want users to be able to basically have 4 sections on the dashboard that will either be custom html or something they can simply enter some info and it generates the "section" for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can simply add a custom function in your `functions.php` with your specific HTML content like this:

```
/* add content */
function customContent() {
  echo '<div><p>Custom Lorem Ipsum Content</p></div>';
} 

/* add action */
add_action('load-index.php', 'customContent');
```

In this vein you are showing some customContent under the Admin Bar within the Dashboard to all Users. But now it will be quite a bit of work to do the styling. So why not use the normal customDashboardWidgets with its functionality and just reset the styling?

```
/* add content */   
function customContent() {
  echo '<div><p>Custom Lorem Ipsum Content</p></div>';
}

/* add widget */
function add_customDashboardWidget() {
  wp_add_dashboard_widget('wp_dashboard_widget', 'Custom Content', 'customContent');
}

/* add action */
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_customDashboardWidget' );
```

And finally you can do some styling:

```
<style type="text/css">
.postbox,
.postbox div.handlediv,
.postbox h3.hndle {
  background: none;
  border: none;                       
}                       
</style>
```

Note: Make sure to close/open the PHP tags before/after the CSS correctly if inserting the styles within your `functions.php`

Comment: This is great. It works perfectly. But how would specify user roles in it? I have LearnDash plugin that's created a new role (i.e. instructor) and I want this role only to be able to see the widget. Would it be possible to edit your code for this please?

Comment: You could do something like this: `function add_customDashboardWidget() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for authors
        if ( in_array( 'author', $user->roles ) ) {
            wp_add_dashboard_widget('wp_dashboard_widget', 'Custom Content', 'customContent');
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you need more control which roles will see widget you could do something like this:

```
function customContent() {
    echo '<div><p>Custom Lorem Ipsum Content</p></div>';
}

function add_customDashboardWidget() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for authors
        if ( in_array( 'author', $user->roles ) ) {
            wp_add_dashboard_widget('wp_dashboard_widget', 'Custom Content', 'customContent');
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_customDashboardWidget' );
```

This will show widget only to users with Author role. You can combine multiple roles as well.

*** Credit for the original solution goes to Sven.

Answer (score 0):

The below function will remove some unwanted boxes from your dashboard. Also It adds a custom box called "Help and Support". You can add any html to this section.

Add the below code to your `functions.php`

```
//Remove unwanted boxes and Add a custom widget called 'Help and Support
function my_custom_dashboard_widgets() {
   global $wp_meta_boxes;
   unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_plugins']);
   unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_primary']);
   unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_secondary']);
   unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_incoming_links']);
   wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_help_widget', 'Themes: Help and Support', 'custom_dashboard_help');
}
function custom_dashboard_help() {
    echo '<p>Support: <a href="#" target="_blank">Support Forum</a><i> (For members only).</i><p><p>Wants to customize your theme by our WordPress Experts? <a href="#" target="_blank">Customize my theme</a> <i>(Our wp Experts will do it for you!)</i></p>';
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I've already got most of that and I'm currently trying to figure out a solution to not use the dashboard widget. Basically I want something that will let you customize the dashboard 100% via a plugin.

So if you wanted a picture of a rainbow, you could set that in an HTML box and it would appear (not inside a widget or any field, just blank as HTML).

Any ideas?